# How to write Junit test case for Dao class?

Tags: junit, tdd, clover

Here is my dao class , can anyone tell me the pattern for this dao method.

```
public String getProcessNames() throws IOException{
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    JSONObject output=new JSONObject();
    String responseGson;
    Session session = ConnectionDAO.getBoltSession();
    String query = qpObj.getQueryValue("neo4j.processMonitor.getProcessNames");
    StatementResult result = session.run(query);
    JSONArray dataArray= new JSONArray();
    try{
        while ( result.hasNext() )
        {
            Record record = result.next();
            responseGson=gson.toJson(record.asMap());
            JSONObject responseJson=new JSONObject(responseGson);
            dataArray.put(responseJson.get("ProcessName"));
            output.put("results",dataArray);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        if(session.isOpen()){
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

or anyone can provide the direct link for reference ,it will be good for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Well, one thing about testing is that it also leads to better code, since bad code is often not very testable. But before we go to that, let's start with a simple consideration: WHAT do you want to test?

a) You can test the method itself, without connecting to the database, which would be a unit test

b) You can test the method and the database result, which would be more an integration test

Personally, I would do both, writing a unit test and an integration test, since both have their uses (the unit test is quicker and can be run much more often, the integration test will test more). But let's start with the unit test...

Your main problem for a unit test is this...

```
Session session = ConnectionDAO.getBoltSession();
```

This static call makes everything hard. Of course you can code your ConnectionDAO in a way to initialize it for a unit test, for example by creating a ...

```
ConnectionDAO.initForTestOnly();
```

...method, but this would imply that your ConnectionDAO has TWO jobs, the first one being the actual DAO and the second one being a test tool. This is not a good idea, since a class should do one thing only.

So, we normally mock stuff. For mocking stuff, you will have to give dependencides into the class to mock instead of hard-coding them into the class, for example...

```
class YourClass {

  private ConnectionDAO connectionDAO;

  public YourClass(ConnectioNDAO connectionDao) {
    this.connectionDAO = connectionDAO;
  }

  public String getProcessNames() throws IOException{
     ...
     Session session =  this.connectionDAO.getBoltSession();
     ...
  }

}
```

This removes the need for a static class and now you can mock your connectionDAO in your test class...

```
class YourClassTest {

   public void testGetProcessNames() throws IOException {
       ConnectionDAO connectionDAOMock = Mockito.mock(ConnectionDAO.class);
       YourClass yourClass = new YourClass(connectionDAOMock);

       //...init the mock here, see the Mockito documentation for that

       String result = yourClass.getProcessNames();


   }

}
```

Perhaps you'll need to do the same with your `qpObj`. Hopefully this basic idea helps a little for a start...